# How to label some lines of a multiline chain of aligned equations

Tags: equations, align

How in LaTeX do I make a multiline chain of equations, aligned on their `=` signs, and label at least one of them but not all of them, in such a way that equation-references work as they should?

The documentation I've seen addresses the task of laying out a single equation which is too long for a line, but not the task of laying out a chain of equations over several lines, with labels on specific lines.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{document}
Text before the equations.
\begin{align*}
f(n+1)&=(n+1)^2 \\\\
&=n^2+2n+1 \label{u} \\\\
&=g(n)+1 \label{v}
\end{align*}
Later I discuss equations \eqref{u} and \eqref{v}.
\end{document}
```

In searching for the way to do this, I've come across many environments, including `align`, `alignat`, `aligned`, `array`, `equation`, `eqnarray` and various of the above suffixed with `*`. None of them seem to both compile and work.

Tobias Oetiker's "The Not So Short Introduction to Latex2e", p.64, sect.3.5.2, recommends `IEEEeqnarray` from the package `IEEEtrantools`. However my installation of TeX (MiKTeX) doesn't contain `IEEEtrantools`, and running `pdflatex` can't find it.

Comment: you might take a look at the documentation for `amsmath` -- `texdoc amsmath`.  there it mentions the use of `\notag` to omit the number from selected lines of a multiline block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example using `\notag`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{document}
Text before the equations.
%\begin{align*}
\begin{align}
f(n+1)&=(n+1)^2 \notag\\
&=n^2+2n+1 \label{u} \\
&=g(n)+1 \label{v}
%\end{align*}
\end{align}
Later I discuss equations \eqref{u} and \eqref{v}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Two things I noted, which I mention just in case they help other beginners: 1) if a run of pdflatex says there were undefined references, or if (after inserting lines into the equation chain, say) a reference is wrong, rerunning pdflatex solves this 2) some display-math constructs work only if /not/ enclosed in $$...$$.

Comment: @RosieF So please observe also, that `\notag` is defined by `amsmath`. Without it standard `\nonumber` works.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke -- without `amsmath`, `align` wouldn't work, so there's a bit of a tautology there.